# Assign Remote MongoDB ip to a Domain Name

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have installed mongoDB in GCP virtual machine. I am using apache reverse proxy to forward my domain 'example.com' to mongoDB port **http://localhost:27017**.

When I try to connect my remote db using:
`mongo -u admin -p admin example.com` it does not work. But when I try connect my remote db using:
`mongo -u admin -p admin remote_ip:27017` it works. How can I make the domain part working. Here is my Apache .conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   
                           ServerName example.com

                           <Proxy balancer://mycluster>
                            BalancerMember http://127.0.0.1:27017
                           </Proxy>

                           ProxyPreserveHost On
                           ProxyPass / balancer://mycluster/
                           ProxyPassReverse / balancer://mycluster/

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Do you have DNS configured properly so that your VM is returned when looking up your domain? Also, I assume you are using a different domain name that you own and 'example.com' is an example?

Answer (score 0):

You made an HTTP proxy. Mongo shell attempts to create a persistent TCP connection, which your proxy doesn't know how to deal with.

I'm not sure if Apache even can do this. It's really just meant to pass on http requests. I do know nginx can do it. Here is more info on how:

https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/load-balancer/tcp-udp-load-balancer/